# What do you call a small gap that allows you to see through something?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for it? I am thinking of things like a keyhole or a small gap in a bush. I am not sure if there's a name for it, but it would really help me out if you could find a word for it.

For example:

> The hunter who hid himself in a small bush saw through a ___ a deer
>   sleeping near a tree.

Comment: Have you checked in a bilingual dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using the simplest general word "gap". In this case it would be a "gap in the foliage". I'd probably phrase it as

> ... saw a deer sleeping by a tree through a gap in the foliage.

<sub>Do deer sleep? I've never seen a sleeping deer.</sub>

Comment: Yes, [it does](https://www.google.com/search?q=sleeping+deer+pics&oq=sleeping+deer+pics+&aqs=chrome..69i57.15496j0j8&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=fw_lMm-C20Ev_M:) :)